# htaccess как перенаправить запросы картинок на другую папку?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Картинки лежат в папке где название папки по первым 2м символам названия файла, например файл **st**ack_help_me.jpg будет лежать в папке
/mnt/images/**st**/**st**ack_help_me.jpg

Задача сделать так чтобы все запросы картинок **определенной подпапки** (например **uploads**) переадресовывались к нужному файлу. Например, /wp-content/**uploads**/2018/12/stack_help_me.jpg

**Как это сделать чисто средствами htaccess и возможно ли?**

На PHP вроде как понятно (хотя наверняка с ошибками по части правил htaccess).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-content/uploads/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) navigator.php?&src=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

И далее код самого navigator.php

```
$real_img_path = '/mnt/images';
$full_path = $_GET['src']; // /wp-content/uploads/2018/12/stack_help_me.jpg
$only_fname = substr($full_path, strrpos($full_path, '/') + 1); // stack_help_me.jpg
$image = $real_img_path . '/' . substr($only_fname, 0, 2) . '/' . $only_fname; // /mnt/images/st/stack_help_me.jpg
fpassthru(fopen($image, 'rb'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Одним только htaccess без дополнительных настроек, т.к. htaccess работает только в рамках рабочей директории домена и глубже.

Поэтому варианты которые я нашел:
1. Использовать в настройках Apache для домена директиву `Alias` https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html , добавить в директиву `<Directory>` путь к папке с картинками `/mnt/images/` , далее в самом htaccess правило

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/\d{4}/\d\d/((..).*\.jpg)$ /mnt/images/$2/$1 [L]
```

2. Symlinks - мягкие на директорию, и тот же самый код htaccess.

Что работает лучше и какой путь я выбрал отпишу позже дополнительно, склоняюсь к Apache.